# Django dictionary parameters issue

Tags: django

I am trying to use Django dictionary parameters when calling `cursor.execute` that is documented in this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw)

I have this test code:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    params = {"server_id": 1}
    cursor.execute(
        ("select * from General.Servers where ServerID = %(server_id)s"), params,
    )
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: format requires a mapping
```

What does this error mean? and how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: In the doc you refer to, there is a note that highlights that SQLite backend does not support dict-flavour parameters. Which kind of database do you use?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a minor mistake. You have to replace `,` by `%` like this.

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    params = {"server_id": 1}
    cursor.execute("select * from General.Servers where ServerID = %(server_id)s" %params)
```

Also move the params inside parentheses.

Comment: using your code, I got this error: "execute() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_id'"

Comment: Had some mistake, extra parenthesis. corrected now. Use this and let me know if it works.

Comment: This may work, but is not equivalent to using cursor with bind parameters. That's highlighted in the long warning in the django doc. Using the pattern suggested in this answer, you generate a string by substituting the parameters names with their respective value. This has both security and performance implications.

Comment: Nielk, can you share link?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    params = {"server_id": 1}
    cursor.execute(
        ("select * from General.Servers where ServerID = %s"), [params],
    )
```

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server